# Issue with Python Classes

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing a simple Python program which is a text-based fighting simulator, and I'm using classes to allow myself to create heroes and enemies. I've created an attack function within my hero class, but it doesn't seem to be subtracting the enemy health from the hero strength like I want it to.

Here's the code:

```
import random

class Enemy:
  eName = "Name"
  eHealth = 0
  eStrength = 0
  def __init__ (self, eName, eHealth, eStrength):
    self.eName = eName
    self.eHealth = eHealth
    self.eStrength = eStrength
  def attack (self):
    print("The enemy attacked you and dealt", self.eStrength, "damage!")
    Hero.health -= self.eStrength
  def __repr__(self):
    if self.eName == "Zombie":
      return "Zombie"
    elif self.eName == "Skeleton":
      return "Skeleton"
    else:
      return "Spider"

class Hero:
  name = "Name"
  health = 0
  strength = 0
  def __init__ (self, name, health, strength):
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.strength = strength
  def attack(self, enemy):
    print("You attacked", enemy, "for", self.strength, "damage!\n")
    Enemy.eHealth -= self.strength
    print(enemy, "now has", enemy.eHealth, "health points left!\n")

print("Welcome to my fighting simulator!")
hName = input("Please input your character's name:\n")
hHealth = int(input("Please enter your hero's amount of health points (10-25):\n"))
hStrength = int(input("Please enter your hero's amount of strength points (2-4): \n"))
character = Hero(hName, hHealth, hStrength)

zombie = Enemy("Zombie", 25, 3)
skeleton = Enemy("Skeleton", 15, 4)
spider = Enemy("Spider", 20, 2)

randEnemy = random.randint(1, 3)

if randEnemy == 1:
  print("\nYour enemy will be a zombie!\n")
  chosenEnemy = zombie
elif randEnemy == 2:
  print("\nYour enemy will be a skeleton!\n")
  chosenEnemy = skeleton
else:
  print("\nYour enemy will be a spider!\n")
  chosenEnemy = spider

while True:
  if character.health == 0:
    print("You died!")
  elif chosenEnemy.eHealth == 0:
    print("You won!")
  action = input("What would you like to do? (h = heal, a = attack): ")
  if (action == 'a') or (action == 'A'):
    character.attack(chosenEnemy)
```

The main things that need to be seen are the variables in the Enemy class, the attack function in the Hero class, and the input variables for the heroes stats.

Comment: Note that `Hero.health` is _not_ the same as `character.health` or `Hero(whatever).health` in general. Same for `Enemy` and instances of `Enemy`, like `zombie` or `skeleton`.

Comment: you need to do `character.health -= self.eStrength` instead of `Hero.health -= self.eStrength`. character is the instance of your class Hero

Comment: Your attack method takes an enemy parameter, but you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You just had a typo. In the `attack()` method, you wrote

```
Enemy.eHealth -= self.strength
```

instead of

```
enemy.eHealth -= self.strength
```

And since you are unable to subtract health from the `Enemy` **class**, the described problem that you mentioned occurs.